# How to make a ShapeDrawable clickable

Tags: android, click, touch

I'm trying to draw some ShapeDrawable into a View and when long clicking on them they should be editable (the text that they have on it).
I just can't figure out how to detect a touch on the ShapeDrawable.
I tried to make it a Button and draw my Shape in its onDraw function like I found here ([How-to create a clickable Button with a ShapeDrawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507578/how-to-create-a-clickable-button-with-a-shapedrawable)) but not even that Button seems to be getting the click event.

How would you solve this problem?

Edit:

@papachan Hm... I tried extending the View class but still no clicks :( My View is getting drawn in the onDraw() of it's superView and it draws a ShapeDrawable with a specific width and height. But I'm never setting the width and heigth in the class containing the View. So may the problem be that it does not know if it got hit by my touch?

Comment: I wonder if you unluckily chose the wrong view to try this. Buttons (in all platforms) tend to eat click events to transform them.

Answer (score 0):

Only Views can be clickables. Have you tried to extend a View?

Comment: This seems like the correct approach. Make the custom component draw the drawable in the onDraw method but also extend View class. This way you can attach a clickListener to the view.

Comment: Hm... I tried extending the View class but still no clicks :( My View is getting drawn in the onDraw() of it's superView and it draws a ShapeDrawable with a specific width and height. But I'm never setting the width and heigth in the class containing the View. So may the problem be that it does not know if it got hit by my touch?